# How do I choose my own name for the MPI communicator?

Tags: fortran, mpi

The name for the default communicator is MPI_COMM_WORLD.  I want it to be mpicomm in my program.  How do I set the communicator to the name I want?

Note, that my program is already working using this variable name, 'mpicomm', but I never actually told the program that that should be the name of the communicator.  I guess the value of MPI_COMM_WORLD is 0 and so is 'mpicomm' when I run the program.  But I don't want this to be working due to a fluke.

For example:

```
program main
use mpi
implicit none
integer :: mpierr, mpicomm, rank
call MPI_Init(mpierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(mpicomm,rank,mpierr)
call MPI_Finalize(mpierr)
end program main
```

This works, and rank comes out to the correct value; however, I don't think this is going to work if MPI_COMM_WORLD happens to be some value besides zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can rely on `mpi_comm_world` being `0`; I just checked an `mpif.h` file I have lying around and in that the value is `91`.  I think you got lucky passing an uninitialised variable (your `mpicomm`) as an input argument in the call to `mpi_comm_rank`.

Since `mpi_comm_world` is, as far as Fortran is concerned, just an integer, why not insert the line

```
mpicomm = mpi_comm_world
```

before you first use `mpicomm` ?  You could probably even declare it like this

```
integer, parameter :: mpicomm = mpi_comm_world
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work.  Simple, yet effective.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Thanks.